# Difference between metal film and carbon film resistors

Tags: arduino, voltage, resistors, metal-film

I have a WS2812B RGB LED strip that I want to use with an Arduino. The [directions](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ws2812-breakout-hookup-guide) state that it's best to use a capacitor and a resistor in order to have smooth operation.

So I bought a *600pcs 30Value 20pcs Each 1% 1/4W Metal Film Resistor Assortment Kit*, not knowing that the directions pointed to a kit that was titled *Resistor Kit - 1/4W (500 total) Carbon Film 5%*.

I hooked up the 1000 µF Capacitor to the power line and grounded the other end (which worked just fine), and also added a 470 Ω resistor to the digital pin on the Arduino.

I added the code and uploaded it to the Arduino, and nothing happened. I fiddled around with it until I found the cause of the issue: the resistor I was using. So I tried 220 Ω and it also would not allow the LED strip to light up.

I then decided to take out the resistor altogether, and things worked just fine.

Now my question is: what is the equivalent of a 470 Ω metal film 1% resistor, since it seems they are using a carbon resistor for this project?

I really do not want to have to purchase another bag of resistors just so I can have some carbon film resistors.

Any information/knowledge would be great! Thanks!

Comment: The difference between metal film and carbon film resistors only really matters in very noise sensitive circuits. For LED current setting, it is inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

Relax. First off, the link does not necessarily point to a carbon assortment - the description does not say. What it does say is that the assortment replaces an earlier kit which did use carbon comps.

Regardless, for what you're doing there is no difference. The composition of the resistors has nothing to do with your problem.

And what is your problem? At a guess, you're reading the color codes wrong. I recommend you get a cheap mulitmeter (you can get them for less than $10 on eBay), and use it to check your resistor values.